# How to make layouts grow and shrink?

Tags: android, xml, layout

I'm playing around with making a random recipe collection app.
Now I came across a problem: at the moment I have designed it with my mobile's resolution in mind. But what if the app is used on a device with larger resolution eg. a tablet.

What I want to achieve is that I want the buttons to grow shrink depending on the resolution. For example: when holding my phone vertically, there are 2 columns of buttons. When holding it horizontally, there still are 2 columns, but the view gets wider. Then there should be 4 columns to fill as much of the white space as possible.

Two pictures to illustrate my thoughts:

[image: vertical] 
*vertical*

[image: horizontal]
*horizontal with 2 more columns*

My code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffcc33"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingTop="10dp"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:paddingRight="10dp" >

<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="1000" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/search_box"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_weight="1000"
        android:ems="5"
        android:hint="@string/search_hint" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/search_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:text="@string/search_button" />

</LinearLayout>

<ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="225dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/search_box"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_lihatoidud"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/lihatoidud"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="Lihatoidud"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_kypsetised"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btn_lihatoidud"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/kypsetised"
            android:text="Küpsetised"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_seenetoidud"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btn_kypsetised"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/seenetoidud"
            android:text="Seenetoidud"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_juustutoidud"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btn_seenetoidud"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/juustutoidud"
            android:text="Juustutoidud"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_lisandid"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btn_juustutoidud"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/lisandid"
            android:text="Lisandid"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_supid"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/supid"
            android:text="Supid"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_voileivad"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btn_supid"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/voileivad"
            android:text="Võileivad"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_pudrud"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btn_voileivad"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/pudrud"
            android:text="Pudrud"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_joogid"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btn_pudrud"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/joogid"
            android:text="Joogid"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would actually reccomend you use the GridView pattern.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

Benfits include

- Easily customize able if you need multiple rows/columns
- Faster performance because you re-use a lot the same views. Scales much better than scrollview approach

[Here example with two column for Phones](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4SYTv.jpg)

[Here example with four column for tablets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6r0E.jpg)

All changing only the number of columns the grid should show. The best way to do this by what "JRaymond" recommended, by having multiple  values resposnes depending on if its a tablet/phone. Example

- ->values ->attrs_arin_view.xml
- ->values-land->attrs_arin_view.xml
- ->values-sw600dp -> attrs_arin_view.xml

inside values ->attrs_arin_view.xml

```
   <resources>
        <integer name="number_of_column">2</integer>
    </resources>
```

and then change in the values-land to have number_of_column to 4.

Then in your in your xml you mention the integer once

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    >

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:horizontalSpacing="8dp"
        android:numColumns="@integer/number_of_column"
        android:padding="8dp"
        tools:listitem="@layout/grid_cell_note"
         >
    </GridView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Android has a few mechanisms for dealing with this kind of thing.  For most people simply having a different layout for different classes of device will be sufficient.  i.e:

```
res/
  layout/
    my_layout.xml
  layout-land/        # landscape
    my_layout.xml
  layout-sw600dp      # bigger devices
    my_layout.xml
  layout-sw600dp-land # Big and landscape
```

Android will automatically pick the right layout on the device your app gets loaded on.  See the [Developer Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers) for details there.  Alternatively, you might need to define your own custom view that resizes your grid based on the available size.  An example of this is a [`CellLayout`](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_launcher/blob/master/src/com/android/launcher/CellLayout.java), a class written for the grid of apps in Launcher

Answer (score 1):

You need to create xml files for different screen sizes

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

design your XML files to use references instead of hardcoded strings. You can then assign a reference to layouts, buttons and so on which has a different value depending on screen sizes.
(use `android:padding="@dimen/pagepadding"` instead of `android:padding="16dp"` and define the dp in values/dimens.xml like this: `<dimen name="pagepadding">16dp</dimen>`)

To do that you have to create new folders in your Project like `values-sw600dp` for devices with 600dp smallest width (like Nexus 7 I believe) or `values-sw720dp-land` for devices with the smallest width of 720dp (10 inch tablets I believe) in landscape.

Do some reading on the developer page and on the internet for that. It's not too difficult